# Is it possible to use one field in a cte to limit the data in another cte

Tags: t-sql, pivot, common-table-expression

I am new to using CTEs but I work with a humongous database and think they would cause less stress to the system that subqueries. I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible.

I have 2 CTEs with different columns from different tables but each CTE has the same sample_num (same data type of int) in them that could be used to join them if possible. I use the first CTE to limit the data for samples. I want the second CTE to look into the first and if the sample numbers match, include that sample number data in the second CTE. The reason I have the second CTE is because I use it's data to create a pivot table.

Ultimately what I want to do in my outer query is to use the fields from the first CTE and add the pivot table columns from the second CTE to the left. Basically marry the two CTEs side by side in the final outer query.

Is this possible or am I making this a lot harder than it needs to be. Remember, I work on a huge database with thousands of users.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and what you want the final output to look like? This seems pretty simple but you'll get help faster with sample data and expected results we can visualize. 

On a separate note: except for the fact that CTEs can be made recursive and Subqueries can be correlated - CTE's and subqueries are exactly the same thing, yield identical execution plans and, thus, perform identically. The difference has to do with Syntax.

Comment: Not 100% clear on your intent, but it seems like you should be looking into Table-Valued Functions in concert with a CROSS APPLY